# Change default sorting for specific Woocommerce product categories archive pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have found this code but it's working only for one category I want to add three or four categories

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_catalog_ordering_args', 20, 1 );
function custom_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $product_category = 't-shirts'; // <== HERE define your product category

    // Only for defined product category archive page
    if( ! is_product_category($product_category) ) return $args;

    // Set default ordering to 'date ID', so "Newness"
    $args['orderby'] = 'date ID';

    if( $args['orderby'] == 'date ID' )
        $args['order'] = 'DESC'; // Set order by DESC

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: What you tried for categories?

Comment: Sorting products